# Android app file cannot be attached and send as an email

Tags: java, android, image-uploading, email-attachments

"File could not be attached"
I am trying to attach an image from my app and send it as an attachment over email. But as soon as I select the image from Gallery, the app crashes. It used to work the first time I executed the app, but now it does not seem to work for some reason. But later I fixed it by updating the line of code to:

```
        attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.d("Attachment Path: "," " + attachmentFile);
```

From my Logcat, I cannot find which statement is causing this issue.

Initially, I was referring to this qeuestion and tried the answers given in this.
"[java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449589/java-lang-nullpointerexception-println-needs-a-message)".

"My DespatchActivity"

```
package com.example.despatch4.resiscafftest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DespatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Activity activity;

Button Attachment;
String attachmentFile;
Uri URI = null;
int columnIndex;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 101;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_despatch);
    this.setTitle("Residential Scaffold - Despatch");


    final EditText your_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_name);
    final EditText company_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.company_name);
    final EditText your_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_ph);
    final EditText your_jobno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_jobno);
    final EditText your_e_d =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_e_d);
    final EditText job_details = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.job_details);
    final EditText your_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_date);

    Button email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_desp_message);
    Attachment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_attach);

    email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String name = your_name.getText().toString();
            String companyname = company_name.getText().toString();
            String phone = your_phone.getText().toString();
            String jobno = your_jobno.getText().toString();
            String ed = your_e_d.getText().toString();
            String jobdetails = job_details.getText().toString();
            String date = your_date.getText().toString();

            Intent sendEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);



            sendEmail.setType("plain/text");
            sendEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"Zamil@residentialscaffold.com.au"});

            sendEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Name: " + name + '\n' + '\n'  + "Company Name: " + companyname + '\n' + '\n'
                    + '\n' + "Contact Number: " + phone + '\n' + '\n'  + "Job Number: " + jobno + '\n' + '\n'  +  "Erect/Dismantle: " + ed + '\n' + '\n'  + "Job Details: "
                    + jobdetails + '\n' + '\n'  + "Date Required: " + date);
                if (URI != null) {
                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImage);
            }
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send mail..."));

        }
    });


    //attach images
    Attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFolder();
        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
Uri selectedImage = null;    
if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        //Log.e("Attachment Path:", " " , attachmentFile);
        Log.d("Attachment Path: ","null" attachmentFile);
        URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
        cursor.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

public void openFolder()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}

}
```

As soon as I try to attach a file this is what happens in my Logcat:

```
 01-23 10:23:48.123 4334-4334/com.example.despatch4.resiscafftest 
 D/Attachment Path:: nullnull
```

The email client is successfully launched with a toast message "Couldn't attach file".

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Updated line of code to:

    String err = attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
     Log.d("Attachment Path: ","null" + err);


Now, the app does not crash. But there is no attachment.

Comment: Well if the path is null then what do you expect? And why do you call a path `err` ? Dont try to get a path but use the obtained uri directly.

Comment: Instead of the null, I tried 
            `Log.d("Attachment Path: "," " + err);`  which does not also give me the attachment. 
But, if I take off the " ", the app crashes with logcat "println needs a statement".

Comment: `selectedImage = data.getData();` That is enough for onActivityResult(); Remove the rest of the code there. Also do not use those other parameters in your code anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
```

change that line to

```
sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, data.getData());
```

With `data.getData()` the one you got in `onActivityResult()`.`

Dont mess around with trying to obtain a path.

Instead use the uri directly.

Much less code too ;-).

Comment: I've tried it. But my `onClick` is not recognising the path from `onActivityResult`, `data.getData()`; 
"Cannot resolve data"

Comment: You should save that in a variable first. Like you store it in `Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`. Change that to `selectedImage = data.getData();` And at the start of your activity `Uri selectedImage = null;`. And then use `selectedImage` in onClick() if it is not null.

Comment: Updated to 
`Uri selectedImage = null;`
`Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`
In my condition of !null:
` if (URI != null) `
`{
   sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedImage);  }`

but now, selected image is not being detected.

I have also updated the code in my question, can you please check that as well.

Comment: `Updated to Uri selectedImage = null; Uri selectedImage = data.getData();` WRONG!!! That should be `Uri selectedImage = null; selectedImage = data.getData();`. Read my instructions again!

Comment: `Uri selectedImage = null;  ` You placed that in onActivityResult(). Take it out! It should be placed at the start of your activity code. And you have already one there as otherwise your code would not compile. You should not have two as you have now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. Now I understood what the mistake was.